# Can I set PDF resolution (pixels per inch) in react-pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

**Some background:**

There is no native pixel resolution for a PDF document. This is because PDF documents are scaled using inches. Each PDF viewer then determines how many pixels it will display per inch (e.g. Adobe Acrobat is 110px/in).

**My problem:**

[React-PDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) uses a default scale of 72ppi. However in many cases this is too small for comfortable reading. I was hoping there may be a way to set up a default PPI of 96.

**What I currently do:**

I scale each `<Page/>` by a factor of `96 / 72`, however I'm worried that this scaling is being applied *after* the main rendering process (i.e. on the pixel output) rather than *as part of* it (i.e. on the source document).

```
<Document file={url}>
  <Page scale={96/72} pageNumber={1}/>
</Document>
```

This could result in bluriness of the final output.

**Possible solution?**

Rendering the document as an SVG may improve final scaled-resolution detail.

```
<Page renderMode="svg"/>
```

Anyone else have some experience working with PPI in react-pdf?

Comment: react pdf is the wrong guy to blame here, as the actual pdf stuff is made by https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit. you need to check there

Comment: sorry forget my comment, i was talking about a completely different react pdf :(

Comment: I can not believe you question answered my question. Thank you a lot. Your scale in your code fixed my problem :))

Comment: Great question! as @AliBayatMokhtari said your question answered mine ..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

They have issue for this staff on GitHub https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1066

So, state on **Aug 2021**, no you can't choose DPI.